# How to transform a 2D and index tensors for torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_sequence

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, lstm

I have a sequences collection in the following form:

```py
sequences = torch.tensor([[2,1],[5,6],[3,0])
indexes = torch.tensor([1,0,1])
```

that is, the sequence `0` is made of just `[5,6]`, and the sequence `1` is made of `[2,1] , [3,0]`. Mathematically `sequence[i] = { sequences[j] such that i = indexes[j] }`

I need to feed these sequences into an [LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstm). Since these are variable-length sequences, pytorch documentation states to use something like [`torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_sequence`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_sequence).

Sadly, this method and its like want, as input, a list of tensors where each of them is a `L x *`, with L being the length of the single sequence.

How can build something that can be fed into a pytorch LSTM?

P.s. throughout the code I work with these tensors using `scatter` and `gather` functionalities but I can't find a way to use them to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative and more efficient way to separate the sequences:

```py
sequences = torch.tensor([[2,1],[5,6],[3,0]])
indexes = torch.tensor([1,0,1])

sorted_src = src[indexes.argsort()]
indexes_count = torch.unique(indexes, return_counts=True)[1]

splitted = torch.split(sorted_src, indexes_count.tolist(), dim=0)
```

This method is almost 3 times faster then the one proposed by @Mercury.

> Measured using `timeit` module with sequences being a (5000,256) tensor and indexes being (1500)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to separate your sequences. Pack_sequence accepts a list of tensors, each tensor being the shape L x *. The other dimensions must always be the same for all sequences, but L, or the sequence length can be varying. For example, your sequence 0 and 1 can be packed as:

```
sequences = [torch.tensor([[5,6]]), torch.tensor([[2,1],[3,0]])]
packed_seq = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_sequence(sequences, enforce_sorted=False)
```

Here, in sequences, sequences[0] is of shape (1,2) while sequences[1] is of shape (2,2). The first dimension represents their length, which is 1 and 2 respectively.

You can separate the sequences by:

```
sequences = torch.tensor([[2,1],[5,6],[3,0]])
indexes = torch.tensor([1,0,1])
num_seq = np.unique(indexes)
sequences = [sequences[indexes==seq_id] for seq_id in num_seq]
```

This creates `sequences=[torch.tensor([[5,6]]), torch.tensor([[2,1],[3,0]])]`.

Comment: yeah I know this, but if following this way, how can I separtae my sequences given the Tensors I described?

Comment: Your indexes tensor must allow you to separate your sequences. From indexes = torch.tensor([1,0,1]), what logic are you following to get sequence 0 and 1?

Comment: It could be that increasing subsets of indices make a sequence. For example, if sequences had 5 tensors, indexes = (0,2,0,1,0) would mean that there are 3 sequences. The first one is made with tensor at index 0 and 2. Second one is made with index position 0 and 1 from remaining tensors. Last one is made with the only remaining item, or index 0. Is this the logic that your sequences follow?

Comment: no, in the case you described you'd have 3 sequences: sequence 0 made of tensors at index 0,2,4, sequence 1 made of tensors at index 3 and sequence 2 made of tensor at index 1. Basically indexes tells you the grouping. group[i] = [ sequences[j] where indexes[j] = i ]